# In Livecycle, How do I hide the first five numbers in a SSN and make the last 4 visible using JS, jquery, or just Livecyle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, livecycle

There has to be a way in LiveCycle to enter a SSN and it automatically hides the numbers entered and keeps the final four visible. LiveCycle may have a solution but I may have to use JS or jQuery.

Comment: Have a look at LiveCycle's string functions http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/workbenchHelp/help.htm?content=000837.html

Answer (score 0):

In LiveCycle, the substring function should be all you need

`substring("123456789",6) will return '6789'`

If you prepend it with 5 asterisks (i.e. `'*****' + substring("123456789",6)` ) you should be able to get the desired output

Comment: This sounds promising but this is my first day on LiveCycle; where is the substring function located or where do I put the substring?

Comment: @LanceBitner beats me, I do not use LifeCycle... I'd guess whenever you want to display the output (i.e. in the view)